# How to view exception information in an AzureFunction log

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

So I have an AzureFunction that looks something like this:

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string message, TraceWriter log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex: ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When failures occur, I can view the log in the portal (or in application insights) and see the error message from the exception, but I can't for the life of me find anywhere to view the full exception details (stack trace, etc.)  Is the full serialized exception actually being logged anywhere?  If not, what's the point of letting me pass the exception to the log.Error() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct the exception plus the stack should be present in Application Insights assuming your function is configured for Application Insights (if not I highly encourage you to do so). There are a few ways you can get to them but I find the easiest to be from the "Failures" menu option in Application Insights. You'll have a listing of the operation names that had failures. Selecting one of the operations will take you into a summary of the various exception types.  You can select the exception type of interest to you and it will then load up all the instances of that exception and give you some suggestions on which one may be of interest (you can sort and such)

Keep in mind that exception details can lag several minutes behind.  This MSDN article covers it well and has the current UI that I see today (it has changed a little over time)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions#diagnosing-failures-using-the-azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the env variable CLI_DEBUG to 1 in your machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73277578