# Why Azure Functions doesn't show exceptions in debugger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am new to Azure Functions and I found that while debugging if my code hit some exception it doesn't show in the debugger (I am using Visual Studio 2019). Also it just logs the exception without stack trace info so it becomes hard to figure out the bug. Right now I am using try catch block and logging the stack trace like this-

```
try
{
    var LoginWithCustomIdAsync = await PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomIDAsync(new LoginWithCustomIDRequest
    {
        CustomId = Data.CallerEntityProfile.Entity.Id,
                TitleId = Data.TitleAuthenticationContext.Id
    });

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.LogInformation(e.Message+"--"+e.StackTrace);
}
```

but I want a better solution. Right now I am running my azure function locally. So is there anything I am missing?

host.json code

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I think function also belongs to dotnet programming, and with VS, they should share same operations when debugging, so can you debug a console app normally in VS?

Comment: yes, does your debugger show when some expectation occurs in Azure function?
Here is a snapshot of exception occurring inside console application

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697845282309931012/790230643778125824/unknown.png

Comment: Sure, when my program went into exception, I will see similar window to show the error info in vs like your screenshot. So, when you debug a function, this window never appeared?

Comment: yes it never appears,  here is a short video showing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xQoFiOgr8n0ygEkIzL3qCj0jge_RwqoU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tiny-wa ok, you were right it does hit the exception but its a bug as well( I am using vs studio 2019 enterprise). when I add a console application to the solution its starts working for azure functions as well and when I remove that temporary console application from solution it stops working for azure functions as well. 
tomorrow I will raise a bug for it. 
Thanks, I wouldn't have noticed that if you didn't mentioned that it works on your system.

Comment: @CarlZhao I think its not the correct answer so I will leave it that way only. Correct answer which worked for me is to change the exception setting. Better turn on all and then keep disabling as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, So what I found that I need to change exception setting in order to get the exception in visual studio and to get exception for running azure function on web you need to add application insight NuGet package and also setup application insight on web.
Then the exception will show in the Application insight Failures window

[Vs studio Exception setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGcS.png)

[Application insight Failures window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp9PG.png)

Answer (score 4):

You have to setup the env variable CLI_DEBUG to 1 in your machine.

Comment: `CLI_DEBUG` is not a documented environment-variable in Azure. While it is used by `Azure.Functions.Cli` I believe that's a dev tool and not part of the Azure Functions runtime.

Comment: @Dai There's no other way to get the full exception in local env without logging it yourself. If you have a better idea...

Comment: by the way you can also set that env var in local.settings.json, under "Values".